# How to render (in pdf) responsive pages in PhantomJS

Tags: responsive-design, phantomjs, print-css

I'm wondering how to render responsive pages using PhantomJS in pdf format.
I have tried so many responsive pages and found that it is printing the pdf using the print css.
So, if the page includes the print css OR screen only css it will render the pdf same as we found via print command preview (Ctrl + p).

Is there any way OR script by which i can get the pdf as I'm seeing them on web browser?

Attaching the file when i tried to get the pdf from  http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/.

Also the main issue is not responsive designes, the issue is print css applied over them.

[example pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxlW9.png)

Comment: Why don't you use `page.render("test.png")` for different viewport sizes?

Comment: @ArtjomB. i want to generate a pdf (not image)

Comment: like @ArtjomB. mentioned, you can do this for pdf as well.

Comment: @AndreyBorisko i know how to make pdf using phantomjs, the issue is with the pdf priniting i.e. pdf printing using print css (@media queries in css files of target), so it is making my pdf as i m printing the page but not like i see it in browsers.

Answer (score 1):

[jorupp](https://gist.github.com/jorupp) came up with a javascript solution in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jorupp/2af4d8583bd592b8331f). It essentially let's you "lock" all the media queries in the document's stylesheets to whatever applies presently, before changing to print mode.

In case the link ever disappears, here's the code:

```js
function process(rule) { 
 if(rule.cssRules) { 
  for(var i=rule.cssRules.length-1; i>=0; i--) { 
   process(rule.cssRules[i]);
  }
 }
 if(rule.type == CSSRule.MEDIA_RULE) {
  if(window.matchMedia(rule.media.mediaText).matches) {
   rule.media.mediaText = "all";
  } else {
   rule.media.mediaText = "not all";
  }
 }
 return rule;
}    
for(var i=0; i<document.styleSheets.length; i++) { 
 process(document.styleSheets[i]);
}
```

Comment: How do I go about using this code snippet? Does it go on the phantomjs page, the page being rendered, etc?

Comment: @TetraDev I used page.evaluate to run this code in my phantomjs app

Comment: @James.K nice, can you post a gist or codepen etc.?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite tricky since there is no option to tell PhantomJS to use the `screen` when rendering as PDF.

You would need to

1. load all the linked stylesheets that contain a print block with [`__utils__.sendAJAX`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html#sendajax),
2. remove `@media print` block (this is quite hard with regex because you need to look out for balanced braces, but relatively easy with plain JS),
3. maybe you even need to rename `@media screen` to `@media print`,
4. remove the linked stylesheet from the document and
5. add a `style` element which has the manipulated stylesheet inside (preferable in the same place as the previous stylesheet) to the DOM.

---

Your page won't look good, because you usually have page breaks and the like with pdf. Also, page width and viewport width are quite hard to get right. Changing the page width doesn't change the viewport, so it won't be the proper responsive that would have with a pixel perfect png. But that is only a solution if you don't need selectable text.

Comment: Thanks,I already knew that making a png is far more better than of pdf,no print and viewport issues in image making (as per i tested).But my project demands it to be in the pdf format (selectable text format unlike image).Removing @media print is looking good (only) idea, i'll test it out. Also, i have produced a formula for perfect viewing i.e. paper width = (  'view_port_width' + (55% of 'view_port_width')).

Comment: hey @artjom B. i have another issue with the pdf generation which is with <a> tags. in resulting pdf a tags are just converted to text, in short they are not hyperlinked anymore. here is the github issue https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10196. Please help if you have something regarding this.